# Загрузка в группу VK картинки python

Tags: python, вконтакте

Проблема: не могу сформировать корректные данные для прикрепление фото (параметр attachments).

Vk api обновилась и теперь нельзя использовать api версии (3.0) до этого можно было использовать id(индикатор фотографии)

```
<type><owner_id>_<media_id>



    def upload(self, url, count, public_page, public_page_post, signed, messages=''):
    """!
        @brief Upload content in VK
        @brief Загружает контент в VK
        @param [in] str url // patch to file
        @param [in] str count // timer post
        @param [in] str public_page //destination address
        @param [in] str public_page_post // destination address (negative for group)
        @param [in] str signed // signed or no
        @param [in] str messages // attach string messages
    """
    token = "___токен______"
    session = vk.Session(
        access_token = '___токен______')
    vk.api.access_token = token
    api = vk.API(session, v='5.7', lang='ru', timeout=10)
    result = api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=public_page)
    print(result)
    upload_url = result['upload_url']
    try:
        img = {'photo': ('img32.jpg', open(url, 'rb'))}
        response = requests.post(upload_url, files=img)
        # print("Response.text", response.text)
        print("Load post in grops")
        result = json.loads(response.text)
        print(result)
        attach = api.photos.saveWallPhoto(photo=result['photo'],
                                          hash=result['hash'],
                                          server=result['server'],
                                          group_id=public_page)
        print(attach)
        Temp = attach[0]['id']
        wait = 60 * 60
        vol = wait * count
        times = (time.time() + vol)
        time.sleep(3)
        #    print("Times: ", times)
        var_times = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(hours=count)
        var_times = var_times - datetime.timedelta(minutes=var_times.minute)
        # print(var_times.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p"))
        # print("Messages %s", messages)
        if signed is True:
            signed = 1

        else:
            # 0 — подписи добавлено не будет
            signed = 0


        if count != 0:
            api.wall.post(from_group=1,
                          owner_id=public_page_post,
                          attachments=Temp,
                          signed=signed,
                          publish_date=int(time.mktime(var_times.timetuple())),
                          message=messages)
        else:
            api.wall.post(from_group=1,
                          owner_id=public_page_post,
                          attachments=Temp,
                          signed=signed,
                          message=messages
                          )
        # count += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
```

Comment: если API v3 не поддерживается, может стоит переписать скрипт на использование нового API?

Comment: вот с этим как раз и проблема не могу прикрепить фото к посту

Answer (score 0):

После того как получил адрес сервера, и загрузил фото на сервер. можешь использовать данную функцию для загрузки

```
def post_photo(media_id, owner_id, img_description, vk_token, vk_group_id, api_version, publish_date=''):
    params = {
        'access_token': vk_token,
        'v': api_version,
        'owner_id': f'-{vk_group_id}',
        'from_group': 1,
        'message': img_description,
        'attachments': f'photo{owner_id}_{media_id}',
        'publish_date': publish_date
    }
    response = requests.post(
        VK_API_URL.format(metod='wall.post'),
        params=params
    )
    response.raise_for_status()
    response = response.json()
    check_vk_response(response)
    return response
```